# Page slide display area

Tags: usability, web-app

I'm questioning which is the best area to display this type of component, to not get lost in technical names, to the type of component I'm referring to is this one:

[Example](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/28494/screenshots/5959510/comments_2x.png)

Should the area of this slide be in relation to the action area or the entire window? (In my scenarios you can imagine to open said slide is by clicking on a record on the table behind)

Scenario 1

[image]

Scenario 2

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scenario 1 seems to be correct. The use of overlay in relation to the "slide" is to mute out other components so the user can focus on the "slide" contents.

There are probably some cases where scenario 2 is valid, but here having the navigation items as well as the comments seems to make the screen too busy and cluttered.